# How to set up Debug mode for Mixpanel on iOS?

Tags: ios, mixpanel

On the [docs](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios#debugging-and-logging) it says the following:

> You can turn on Mixpanel logging by adding the following Preprocessor Macros in Build Settings: MIXPANEL_LOG=1 and MIXPANEL_DEBUG=1.

So that's what I did:
[image]

But non of my events show up in the console :(

This is how I track events:

```
Mixpanel *mixpanel = [Mixpanel sharedInstance];
[mixpanel track:@"TEST"];
```

Answer (score 7):

I belive you are using CocoaPods to install the Mixpanel library. In this case, the library is actually compiled separately before it is included in your project. You need to open the `Pods` project in your workspace and choose the `Pods-Mixpanel` target and set the preproccessor macros there, so that they are evaluated when the Mixpanel library compiles.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fuller view for where the Mixpanel based preprocessor macros should be added:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, I couldn't find "Preprocessor Macros" in "Apple LLVM 6.1" section. Finally, I can find it by clicking "ALL" segment button. Thanks!